# Why are the variables in my string not concatenating with the join function?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that sorts all the digits in an integer in reverse. I am trying to get [5431] but instead the output is [5, 4, 3, 1]. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly with the join function.

```
  def Descending_Order(num):
      num = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
      num.sort(reverse=True)
      num = str(num)
      "".join(num)
      print num
  Descending_Order(1534)
```

Comment: you have to assign it. `num = "".join(num)`

Answer (score 1):

Look at that :

```
 num = str(num)
```

num is array, so str(num) is a string '[5, 4, 3, 1]', then you "".join(one string) bug give out num.
The right is :

```
def Descending_Order(num):
  num = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
  num.sort(reverse=True)

  print ("".join(str(x) for x in  num))
Descending_Order(1534)
```

Comment: So str(num) does not create a list ['5', '4', '3', '1']? In order to do that you have to use list comprehension?

Comment: repea. after  num.sort(reverse=True), num is a list. str(list) creates one string. you must do lost comperehension (generator in this example), and join  in

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version that you might like:

```
def Descending_Order(num):

    return "".join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True))

print(Descending_Order(1534))
```

Expected Result:

```
5431
```